# python peewee docs: example app: unknown syntax / feature

Tags: python, operators, operator-overloading, peewee

As I was reading [peewee docs](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.2/peewee/example.html#doing-subqueries), I found a surprising statement:

```
# python code
messages = Message.select().where(
    Message.user << user.following()
)
```

Wow, can someone please explain what does that do? I know that `<<` is just a lshift (left shift) operator (which moves the binary representation left for intergers, similar behavior applies to right shift), but I didn't know this can handle lists (`user.following()` is a list). Is it just operator overloading written by peewee authors or some kind of a python core feature I don't know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pewee indeed [uses operator overloading](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/a9a00fc539a5ed3f3b2607c563c10f962b2b1a6e/peewee.py#L253), in this case with the [`__lshift__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lshift__) magic method.

Comment: You mentioned line `__lshift__ = _e(OP_IN)`, then it's used in `OP_IN: 'IN'` and in django map: `'in': OP_IN`. Do I understand it correctly, that above code is mapped to SQL: `user_id IN (user_following_id1, user_following_id2, ...)`?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz Yes, but instead of statically setting the IDs, these are computed in a subquery. The full SQL is right there in [the doc you linked](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.2/peewee/example.html#doing-subqueries) ;)

Comment: damn, you're right... So I guess this `Message.user << user.following()` has to return something SQL-alike (a SQL-clause string or an object that will be later converted into SQL-clause). Just wanted to understand how does it all work inside. Thanks, man :)

Comment: Author of peewee here, feel free to join #peewee on irc.freenode.net if you'd like to chat about how peewee works.